# Array of hashes to hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

For example, I have array of single hashes

```
a = [{a: :b}, {c: :d}]
```

What is best way to convert it into this?

```
{a: :b, c: :d}
```

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You may use

```
a.reduce Hash.new, :merge
```

which directly yields

```
{:a=>:b, :c=>:d}
```

Note that in case of collisions the order is important. Latter hashes override previous mappings, see e.g.:

```
[{a: :b}, {c: :d}, {e: :f, a: :g}].reduce Hash.new, :merge   # {:a=>:g, :c=>:d, :e=>:f}
```

Comment: `Hash.new`, or as friends like to call him, `{}` :-) So much as I like pure functional solution, note that `merge` will create a new hash on every iteration; we can use `update` instead (it won't mess up with the input hashes, that's the important point): `hs.reduce({}, :update)`

Comment: @tokland, post your comment as a separate answer - it should get more visibility

Comment: If your application allows for it, the `:update` version suggested by tokland is the faster option.

Answer (score 59):

You can use `.inject`:

```
a.inject(:merge)
#=> {:a=>:b, :c=>:d}
```

[**Demonstration**](https://repl.it/ByEz)

Which initiates a new hash on each iteration from the two merged. To avoid this, you can use destructive `:merge!`( or `:update`, which is the same):

```
a.inject(:merge!)
#=> {:a=>:b, :c=>:d}
```

[**Demonstration**](https://repl.it/ByEz/1)

Comment: Thats crazy elegant. Thank you.

Answer (score 25):

These two are equivalent (reduce/inject are the same method):

```
total_hash = hs.reduce({}) { |acc_hash, hash| acc_hash.merge(hash) }
total_hash = hs.reduce({}, :merge)
```

Note that `Hash#merge` creates a new hash on each iteration, which may be a problem if you are building a big one. In that case, use `update` instead:

```
total_hash = hs.reduce({}, :update)
```

Alternatively, you can convert the hashes to pairs and then build the final hash:

```
total_hash = hs.flat_map(&:to_a).to_h
```

Answer (score 5):

I came across this answer and I wanted to compare the two options in terms of performance to see which one is better:

1. `a.reduce Hash.new, :merge`
2. `a.inject(:merge)`

using the ruby benchmark module, it turns out that option (2) `a.inject(:merge)` is faster.

code used for comparison:

```rb
require 'benchmark'

input = [{b: "c"}, {e: "f"}, {h: "i"}, {k: "l"}]
n = 50_000

Benchmark.bm do |benchmark|
  benchmark.report("reduce") do
    n.times do
      input.reduce Hash.new, :merge
    end
  end

  benchmark.report("inject") do
    n.times do
      input.inject(:merge)
    end
  end
end
```

the results were

```
       user     system      total        real
reduce  0.125098   0.003690   0.128788 (  0.129617)
inject  0.078262   0.001439   0.079701 (  0.080383)
```

Comment: This result confused me. The [docs](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) say `reduce` and `inject` are aliased.  A quick check w/ your test shows the slowdown is due to `Hash.new` as the initializer.
`:merge` creates a new hash each iteration. `:update` doesn't. So, a re-run with `:update` shows, even with the `Hash.new`, the `:update` version is faster:```
       user     system      total        real
reduce w/ Hash.new & :update  0.056754   0.002097   0.058851 (  0.059330)
reduce w/ :merge only                0.090021   0.001081   0.091102 (  0.091257)```

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
a.reduce(:merge)
#=> {:a=>:b, :c=>:d}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
a.inject({}){|acc, hash| acc.merge(hash)} #=> {:a=>:b, :c=>:d}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform it to array `[[:a, :b]]` and after that translate everything to hash `{:a=>:b}`

```rb
# it works like [[:a, :b]].to_h => {:a=>:b}

[{a: :b}, {c: :d}].map { |hash| hash.to_a.flatten }.to_h

# => {:a=>:b, :c=>:d}
```