# How to use Ruby's "value_at" to get subhashes in a hash

Tags: ruby

I have a simple collection:

```
{
    :metadata=>{:latitude=>25.86222, :longitude=>-80.27901}, 
    :components=>{:primary_number=>"4390", :street_predirection=>"E"},    
    :analysis=>{:footnotes=>"N#", :dpv_footnotes=>"AABB"}
}
```

I want this:

```
{:latitude=>25.86222, :longitude=>-80.27901,  :primary_number=>"4390", :street_predirection=>"E",:footnotes=>"N#", :dpv_footnotes=>"AABB" }
```

In other words, I don't care about the first-level keys. I just care about everything else and I want to iterate through everything else as such:

```
my_hash.each {|k,v| ... }
```

I looked through the [Hash class](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) and felt that `values_at` will help simplify this task. So I tried:

```
Record.first.mail_validation
# => {:metadata=>{:county_name=>"Miami-Dade", :latitude=>25.86222, :longitude=>-80.27901, :time_zone=>"Eastern", :rdi=>"Residential"}, :components=>{:primary_number=>"4390", :street_predirection=>"E", :street_name=>"2nd", :street_suffix=>"Ave", :secondary_number=>nil, :secondary_designator=>nil, :city_name=>"Hialeah", :state_abbreviation=>"FL", :zipcode=>"33013", :plus4_code=>"2249"}, :analysis=>{:footnotes=>"N#", :dpv_footnotes=>"AABB", :dpv_match_code=>"Y"}} 
Record.first.mail_validation.keys
# => [:metadata, :components, :analysis]
```

This returns no results, since the argument to `values_at` is a string and I pass an array:

```
Record.first.mail_validation.values_at(Record.first.mail_validation.keys)
# => [nil]
```

This doesn't work, because although I pass string as arguments to `values_at`, the keys in the hash are symbols, not keys:

```
Record.first.mail_validation.values_at(Record.first.mail_validation.keys.join(", "))
# => [nil]
```

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: `values_at` takes an array of symbols, as far as I'm aware, something like `{a: 1, b: 2}.values_at(:a, :b)` which returns `[1, 2]`.

Comment: @maxpleaner No it doesn't. I have irb open right now and it is not taking it: Record.first.mail_validation.values_at([:metadata, :components, :anaylsis])  => [nil] . But this does work: Record.first.mail_validation.values_at(:metadata, :components, :anaylsis). I just don't know how to achieve the latter since join(", ") will produce a string.

Comment: I do not want to hardcode the keys. I want to get them from Record.first.mail_validation.keys.

Comment: Oh yes of course you're right. You should use the splat operator, I'll post an answer to show

Comment: What’s wrong with `Record.first.mail_validation.values`?

Comment: In future consider waiting longer before selecting an answer. There's no rush, and you don't want to discourage other answers or short-circuit those still working on answers. Many here wait at least a couple of hours.

Comment: @mudasobwa values would be a better fit for this situation, you are right. When I wrote the question about values_at, it is because I was skimming through the documentation and found values_at and hence asked my question based on what I found in the documents.

Comment: Your question is an "[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153968)". You're asking how to use the solution you decided would work, but it's not the right way to do it. In addition, you needed to read the documentation for `values_at` more closely, because it doesn't take a string, it takes individual key values, which could be a string, an integer, or any object that matches the key. Because of the confusion in the question this should have been closed as an unclear question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have a hash like:

```
hash = { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

You can use `hash.keys` to get

```
[:a, :b]
```

How do you pass these keys into `values_at`, which uses sequential parameters and not an array?

Use the "splat" operator, which will take the array's elements and use them for the sequential parameters. See "[Using splats to build up and tear apart arrays in Ruby](http://blog.honeybadger.io/ruby-splat-array-manipulation-destructuring/)" for more information.

For example:

```
hash.values_at(*hash.keys)
```

returns:

```
[1, 2]
```

In your case, it would be almost the exact same as your original code. Instead of:

```
Record.first.mail_validation.values_at(Record.first.mail_validation.keys)
```

You'd write:

```
Record.first.mail_validation.values_at(*Record.first.mail_validation.keys)
```

Comment: Cool, and then this will be how I merge the array of hashes into one hash: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943909/array-of-hashes-to-hash

Comment: This is really silly. Given a hash `x`, running `x.values_at(*x.keys)` is completely redundant. Just use `x.values` to get the *values* in a hash.

Comment: I agree it does seem silly to do this in practice, but I posted this answer just to show how it can be done. The question is specifically "how to use rubys values_at"

Comment: While the OP asked about an "[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153968)", this is a good answer to the question asked and doesn't deserve being down-voted.

Answer (score 3):

```
hash.each_with_object({}) { |(_, v), memo| memo.merge! v }
#⇒ {
#        :dpv_footnotes => "AABB",
#            :footnotes => "N#",
#             :latitude => 25.86222,
#            :longitude => -80.27901,
#       :primary_number => "4390",
#  :street_predirection => "E"
# }
```

or:

```
hash.values.reduce &:merge
```

Comment: `.values.reduce(&:merge)` is the real answer here

Comment: Good answer, good suggestion (@meagar) and great formatting.

Comment: @meagar Feel free to post your own answer. The real answer here is given above. `each_with_object` is more than twice faster, and this is a common approach to use it always, just in case. And no, this is not a premature optimization, it’s a matter of good habit.

Comment: No, it is not a "good habit" to employe more complex solutions where they are not needed. There are **three** values in the top-level array, measuring the difference in performance is practically impossible. Use the one-liner that is 27 characters long, rather than the 8 line solution that is 270 characters long.

Answer (score 2):

```
h = {
    :metadata=>{:latitude=>25.86222, :longitude=>-80.27901}, 
    :components=>{:primary_number=>"4390", :street_predirection=>"E"},    
    :analysis=>{:footnotes=>"N#", :dpv_footnotes=>"AABB"}
} 

h.values.flat_map(&:to_a).to_h
  #=> {:latitude=>25.86222, :longitude=>-80.27901, :primary_number=>"4390",
  #    :street_predirection=>"E", :footnotes=>"N#", :dpv_footnotes=>"AABB"}
```

The steps:

```
a = h.values
  #=> [{:latitude=>25.86222, :longitude=>-80.27901},
  #    {:primary_number=>"4390", :street_predirection=>"E"},
  #    {:footnotes=>"N#", :dpv_footnotes=>"AABB"}] 
b = a.flat_map(&:to_a)
  #=> [[:latitude, 25.86222], [:longitude, -80.27901], [:primary_number, "4390"],
  #    [:street_predirection, "E"], [:footnotes, "N#"], [:dpv_footnotes, "AABB"]] 
b.to_h
  #=> {:latitude=>25.86222, :longitude=>-80.27901, :primary_number=>"4390",
  #    :street_predirection=>"E", :footnotes=>"N#", :dpv_footnotes=>"AABB"}
```

Comment: No reason to break the values into arrays only to reconstitute them into hashes. Just merge the values.

Comment: @meagar, I agree, but that would have been too close to mudsie's answer (which I would have given had it been available, so I gave this one just for variety).

Answer (score -1):

This works for your example:

```
hash2 = {}
hash.map{ |k,v| hash2.merge!(v) }.first
```

returns:

```
{:latitude=>25.86222, :longitude=>-80.27901, :primary_number=>"4390",
 :street_predirection=>"E", :footnotes=>"N#", :dpv_footnotes=>"AABB"}
```

Comment: This is a pretty incorrect use of `map` and *nothing* like idiomatic Ruby code. It might produce the right result, but nobody should write code this way.

Comment: @meagar would `hash.map.with_object({}) {|(k,v),o| o.merge!(v)}` be better?

Comment: No, you're not *mapping* one thing to another thing, `map` is not only not necessary, it is *wrong*. It implies a *mapping* operation where there isn't one, making your code unnecessarily confusing to anybody trying to read it. This is a **reduction**, the correct method is `reduce`, not `map`.