# format JSON output in ruby

Tags: json, ruby

```
a = [{"a":1},{"b":2}]
```

I want my output should be

```
[{ "a":1, "b":2 }]
```

How to do the format in ruby?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array of hashes to hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943909/array-of-hashes-to-hash)

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to merge the hashes? If so see the answer above of Sebastian. Or do you want to keep the string keys instead of symbols? Or maybe both ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with:

```
[[{"a":1},{"b":2}].inject(:merge)]
# => [{:a=>1, :b=>2}]
```

Which iterates over the array and merges each hash, then closes it all in an array. I really doubt you need to close your hash in an array as the last step though.

Comment: getting NoMethodError

Comment: Can you paste complete code? If you paste my answer in IRB, it does exactly what you asked for.